# How can I catch errors that occur when ggplot objects are evaluated within a pipe?

Tags: r, ggplot2, error-handling, purrr, officer

I'm producing daily powerpoint slidedecks from raw Covid case data, and today, we have no cases!  Excellent, except it broke my reports :-(

I generate ggplots, and place them on powerpoint slides using *officer*.  The ggplot errors only arise when it is evaluated by officer, inside the slide creation pipeline.

I could catch the errors upstream, but doing it right before slide generation makes the code nicer, because the slide generation process is many layered, and it would be good to be able to continue to produce the artifact despite the error.

Reprex follows:

<sup>Note, the error does not occur in R 3.6, probably due to a change in the way *scale_x_discrete* evaluates labels, but it would still be good to have a general way to fail gracefully</sup>

```r
library( stringr )
library(ggplot2)
library(officer)

data = structure(list(LGA = character(0), Sex = character(0)), row.names = integer(0), class = c("tbl_df",
"tbl", "data.frame"))


plot = ggplot( data, aes( LGA, Sex ) ) + 
  geom_point() +
  scale_x_discrete(labels = function(x) str_wrap(x, width = 15)) 

  read_pptx() %>%
    add_slide( )  %>%
    ph_with( plot, location=ph_location_type() )
#> Warning in rep(yes, length.out = len): 'x' is NULL so the result will be NULL
#> Error in ans[ypos] <- rep(yes, length.out = len)[ypos]: replacement has length zero
```

<sup>Created on 2021-01-19 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

It seems that I should be able to use purrr::possibly to catch the error, but it expects a function:

```
Error: Can't convert a `gg/ggplot` object to function
```

Note: eliminated second example

Sessioninfo below:

```
> sessionInfo()
R version 4.0.3 (2020-10-10)
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
Running under: Windows Server x64 (build 14393)

Matrix products: default

locale:
[1] LC_COLLATE=English_Australia.1252  LC_CTYPE=English_Australia.1252
[3] LC_MONETARY=English_Australia.1252 LC_NUMERIC=C
[5] LC_TIME=English_Australia.1252

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base

other attached packages:
[1] purrr_0.3.4      officer_0.3.15   ggplot2_3.3.3    stringr_1.4.0
[5] nvimcom_0.9-92.3

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
 [1] xml2_1.3.2       magrittr_2.0.1   tidyselect_1.1.0 munsell_0.5.0
 [5] uuid_0.1-4       colorspace_1.4-1 R6_2.5.0         rlang_0.4.8
 [9] dplyr_1.0.2      tools_4.0.3      grid_4.0.3       gtable_0.3.0
[13] withr_2.3.0      ellipsis_0.3.1   tibble_3.0.4     lifecycle_0.2.0
[17] crayon_1.3.4     zip_2.1.1        vctrs_0.3.4      glue_1.4.2
[21] stringi_1.5.3    compiler_4.0.3   pillar_1.4.6     generics_0.1.0
[25] scales_1.1.1     pkgconfig_2.0.3
>
```

Comment: Your first example runs without error for me. Your second example runs without error and returns the same result as long as I remove `possibly()` from the last line

Comment: @Mako212, can you please post your sessionInfo()?  Possibly I need to upgrade a package

Comment: I don't really understand your workflow, but isn't it possible to insert a test of whether `ggplot_build(plot)` succeeds before starting to make the slide, and substituting some blank plot if it fails?  E.g. `if (inherits(try(ggplot_build(plot)), "try-error")) plot <- BLANKPLOT`

Comment: @user2554330, that totally works!  I wrap my plots in calls to the try_plot, defined as:
try_plot = function( plot ) { if (inherits(try(ggplot_build(plot)), "try-error")) plot <-ggplot()}

You are a gun!.  Happy to give you the green tickmark if you post it as an answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error happens when the plot is built by `ggplot_build()`.  Normally you don't call this directly, it's called by the functions that display the object, but you can call it yourself.  For example,

```
if (inherits(try(ggplot_build(plot)), "try-error")) 
  plot <- ggplot()
```

will replace a bad plot by a blank one.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not 100% sure this is your issue since I can't replicate the error, but you might try wrapping your ggplot call in `tryCatch()` to handle the error:

```
tryCatch({
    plot <- ggplot( data, aes( LGA, Sex ) ) + 
      geom_point() +
      scale_x_discrete(labels = function(x) str_wrap(x, width = 15)) 

      read_pptx() %>%
        add_slide( )  %>%
        ph_with( plot, location=ph_location_type() )
    }, error = function(e) {
        message(as.character(e)) # exclude this line to return NULL quietly
        return(NULL)
    }
 )
 read_pptx() %>%
            add_slide( )  %>%
            ph_with( plot, location=ph_location_type() )
```

If I make a deliberate error in the ggplot call changing `geom_point()` to `geom_pointesa()` you'll get the following:

> Error in geom_pointesa(): could not find function "geom_pointesa"

> NULL

Note that the `ggplot` call returns `NULL` in this case, while printing an error message for review.

`sessionInfo()` below:

```
R version 3.6.2 (2019-12-12)
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
Running under: Windows 10 x64 (build 18362)

Matrix products: default

locale:
[1] LC_COLLATE=English_United States.1252  LC_CTYPE=English_United States.1252    LC_MONETARY=English_United States.1252 LC_NUMERIC=C                          
[5] LC_TIME=English_United States.1252    

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
[1] officer_0.3.16 ggplot2_3.2.1  stringr_1.4.0 

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
 [1] Rcpp_1.0.3       xml2_1.2.2       magrittr_2.0.1   tidyselect_1.1.0 munsell_0.5.0    uuid_0.1-4       colorspace_1.4-1 R6_2.5.0         rlang_0.4.9     
[10] dplyr_1.0.2      tools_3.6.2      grid_3.6.2       gtable_0.3.0     withr_2.3.0      ellipsis_0.3.1   lazyeval_0.2.2   tibble_2.1.3     lifecycle_0.2.0 
[19] crayon_1.3.4     zip_2.1.1        purrr_0.3.3      vctrs_0.3.5      glue_1.4.2       stringi_1.4.4    compiler_3.6.2   pillar_1.4.7     generics_0.1.0  
[28] scales_1.1.1     pkgconfig_2.0.3
```

Comment: Thanks for that @Mako212.  I don't want to use tryCatch in this way because I want to continue building the slide via the pipeline if there is an error.  I just want to replace that particular graph with 'BLANK', for example.  

Could you please post  your sessionInfo(), so I can see the difference with mine?

Comment: @Dennis I've added `sessionInfo()` to my post. Hopefully that helps.

Comment: I verify that it works in R3.6, probably due to the way that scale_x_discrete evaluates it's arguments, but it still would be good to have a way to fail gracefully...